# How can I quantize a keras model while converting it to a TensorflowJS Layers Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, tensorflow.js, quantization

I created a tensorflow model and then converted it into tensorflow.js model using below code:

```
import tensorflowjs as tfjs
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

classifier = load_model("model")
tfjs.converters.save_keras_model(classifier, "js")
```

It works fine and now I would like to reduce the size of the model using quantization when converting it to a TensorflowJS Layers Model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible you have four options for quantization:

1. --quantization_bytes(depreceated)
2. --quantize_float16
3. --quantize_uint8
4. --quantize_uint16

Example conversion from keras format to tfjs_layers_model:

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
   --input_format keras \
   --output_format tfjs_layers_model \
   --quantize_uint16 \
   original_model/model.json
   quantized_model/
```

Or if you need more help with the entire process just type the following in your terminal

```
tensorflowjs_wizard
```

[More info from Tensorflowjs Converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-converter)

Comment: Thank you! Is it possible to use these options into the python code?

Comment: Hi you do all this from your terminal if you have Tensorflowjs installed on your system you will have no issues. If you are a bit confused about the entire process then just use Tensorflowjswizard.

Comment: I could do the quantification using the command line tool. Thank you.
I wanted to to it in python but it is not possible right?

Comment: Based on the documentation its only available from the command line

Answer (score 0):

Using the command line tool, I could convert my model to quantified tensorflow.js model.

I used below command:

```
~/.local/bin/tensorflowjs_converter model/ quantized_model/
--input_format tf_saved_model --output_format tfjs_graph_model --quantize_uint8
```

I installed python model as a user, so commandline tools are in: *~/.local/bin/*